# Transposing a 3-d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a `numpy` array `A` with shape `(5,24,1)`.
I want to take five separate transposes along `axis = 0`, such that the resulting shape after transposes is `(5,1,24)`.
How can I do this using some of the `numpy` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three approaches could be suggested -

```
A.swapaxes(1,2)
A.transpose(0,2,1)
np.rollaxis(A,2,1)
```

For `swapaxes` and `transpose`, please follow their docs.

With [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html), we are rolling the axes to bring the third axis into the second position and thus pushing back the second axis into third axis position. More info in the linked docs.

Using the fact that the last axis is singleton -

```
A[:,None,:,0]
```

Comment: Works correct. Thanks , can you explain a bit please ! ntw I used `A.transpose(0,2,1)`

Comment: @Divakar You forgot `moveaxis` :-P

Comment: @MSeifert Not really a fan of `moveaxis`, too many characters ;) But yeah that's another alternative and should complete the set of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) (one option missing from Divakars excellent answer) where you can define which axis should be moved:

```
np.moveaxis(A, (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1))
```

This moves axis `0` to `0` (no change, could also be omitted), `1` to `2` and `2` to `1`. So this basically just swaps axis 1 and 2.

```
>>> A = np.ones((5,24,1))
>>> res = np.moveaxis(A, (1, 2), (2, 1))   # this time without the zeros
>>> res.shape
(5, 1, 24)
```

Comment: Just came to me, `reshape` would complete it ;) But I guess its close to what I suggested at the end, without specifying the shape params.

Comment: @Divakar Correct, but that belongs in the category "works here because one dimension is of size 1 but doesn't _actually_ transpose", like your `A[:,None,:,0]`. I tend to avoid these special case solutions in answers, because that likely results in follow-up questions. :D